# MS Exchange Web-Services: How to get items with 'Flag' set?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Does anyone know how to get all the **items that are flagged inside the Inbox** using Microsoft Exchange Web-Services?

Apparently they are neither inside Tasks folder (even though they appear there in Outlook), nor do they have `IsReminderSet` set to *true*.

Following attempts either return only appointments or true tasks only, but not flagged messages:

```
var msgsView = new ItemView(100);
var msgsFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.IsReminderSet, true);
var flagged = exSvc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, msgsFilter, msgsView);
```

or

```
var taskView = new ItemView(100);
var tasks = exSvc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, taskView);
```

neither work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just found list sample code which looks like it might do the trick (I haven't tested it myself yet) 
source: http://independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/findmessageswithflag.html

```
    IsEqualTo restriction1 = new IsEqualTo(MessagePropertyPath.FlagStatus, "1"); //FlagStatus.Complete
    IsEqualTo restriction2 = new IsEqualTo(MessagePropertyPath.FlagStatus, "2"); //FlagStatus.Marked

    Or restriction3 = new Or(restriction1, restriction2);

    FindItemResponse response = service.FindItem(StandardFolder.Inbox
                 , MessagePropertyPath.AllPropertyPaths, restriction3);

for (int i = 0; i < response.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (response.Items[i] is Message)
    {
         Message message = (Message)response.Items[i];

         Console.WriteLine("Subject = " + message.Subject);
         Console.WriteLine("FlagStatus = " + message.FlagStatus);
         Console.WriteLine("FlagIcon = " + message.FlagIcon);
         Console.WriteLine("FlagCompleteTime = " + message.FlagCompleteTime);
         Console.WriteLine("FlagRequest = " + message.FlagRequest);
         Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```